# Showing $(P\to Q)\land (Q\to R)\equiv (P\to R)\land[(P\leftrightarrow Q)\lor (R\leftrightarrow Q)]$ {without truth table}

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

**Problem:** Show $(P\to Q)\land (Q\to R)\equiv (P\to R)\land[(P\leftrightarrow Q)\lor (R\leftrightarrow Q)]$

---

**Source:** As was noted in the [original post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502656/show-by-using-logical-connectives-laws-that-p-to-q-land-q-to-r-is-equiv), this problem is from Daniel J. Velleman's book *How to Prove It*. The exercise may be found as problem 7 (a) on page 54 (second edition). I got a copy of this book, and I saw that some exercises have solutions in the book. The exercise directly before this one had the solution, "Either make a truth table or reason as follows: [...]". This makes me think the author had a truth table solution in mind for this exercise, as a purely direct proof by using a chain of logical equivalences has proven to be exceedingly difficult. I am very interested in obtaining a solution that uses a chain of logical equivalences similar to my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143078/p-leftrightarrow-sim-q-equiv-sim-p-wedge-q-vee-p-wedge-sim-q/1143116#1143116) problem. I have spent several hours working on this problem now, but I have not succeeded at all--I cannot seem to "pull the right-hand side out of the left-hand side", as this seems the most natural approach. For anyone interested, I have presented a truth table without the fluff below.

---

**Truth table solution:**

$$
\boxed{
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
P & Q & R & (P\to Q)\land (Q\to R) & (P\to R)\land[(P\leftrightarrow Q)\lor (R\leftrightarrow Q)] \\ \hline
T & T & T         & T                & T \\
T & T & F         & F                & F \\
T & F & T         & F                & F \\
T & F & F         & F                & F \\
F & T & T         & T                & T \\
F & T & F         & F                & F \\
F & F & T         & T                & T \\
F & F & F         & T                & T 
\end{array}}
$$

---

**Chain of equivalences proof:** It seems that the main issue is "coaxing" the right-hand side out of the left-hand side. For instance, by using distributivity, I can see that somehow $(P\to Q)\land(Q\to R)$ is equivalent to
$$
[(P\to R)\land(P\to Q)\land(Q\to P)]\lor[(P\to R)\land(R\to Q)\land(Q\to R)].\tag{1}
$$
I have tried numerous times trying to manipulate the left-hand side into the expression given in $(1)$, but I have not succeeded so far--everything is such an enormous mess. Perhaps there is some strategy involved in using equivalences (in terms of ease of manipulation); for example, should one use
$$
P\leftrightarrow Q\equiv (P\land Q)\lor(\neg P\land\neg Q)
$$
or
$$
P\leftrightarrow Q\equiv (P\to Q)\land (Q\to P)
$$

Comment: That sounds tedious, but doesn't conjunctive normal form always work?

Comment: @Tunococ I'm not sure what you mean by "always work", but I agree that this problem is ridiculously tedious (on the surface anyway). I'm curious if there are any propositional calculus wizards on MSE like Cleo the integral wizard. I can't even get a brute-force method to work by splitting *everything* apart on the right-hand side. It's just a  complete and utter mess.

Comment: I'm saying that it should not be difficult to show that both expressions reduce to $(P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge R) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge \neg R)$. (I use the disjunctive normal form because it's easier for me to think about. Other normal forms should work too.)

Comment: @crash Wow, if I had known what I'm triggering, I would have just skipped this problem yesterday. Thought I was easy, keeping people busy for hours was not my intention.

Comment: @Dominik That's part of the beauty of MSE though isn't it? People love math here just for math's sake. Your problem interested me, and so I ran with it. Was quite fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several algorithms to convert classical propositional sentences into normal forms. I'll pretend to be as dumb as a computer and convert the two sentences into their disjunctive normal form in a systematic way.

\begin{align}
& {(P \to R) \wedge [(P \leftrightarrow Q) \vee (R \leftrightarrow Q)]}\\
& = (\neg P \vee R) \wedge [(P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (R \wedge Q) \vee (\neg R \wedge \neg Q)] \\
& = [(\neg P \vee R) \wedge P \wedge Q] \vee [(\neg P \vee R) \wedge \neg P \wedge \neg Q] \vee \\
& \phantom{{} = {}} [(\neg P \vee R) \wedge R \wedge Q] \vee [(\neg P \vee R) \wedge \neg R \wedge \neg Q] \\
& = [P \wedge Q \wedge R] \vee [(\neg P \wedge \neg Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge R)] \\
& \phantom{{} = {}} \vee [(\neg P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee (Q \wedge R)] \vee
[\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge \neg R] \\
& = (P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee [(\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge \neg R) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge R)] \vee\\
& \phantom{{}={}} [(\neg P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee (P \wedge Q \wedge R)]
\vee [\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge \neg R] \\
& = (P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge R) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge \neg R) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q \wedge R).
\end{align}
\begin{align}
& (P \to Q) \land (Q \to R) \\
& = (\lnot P \lor Q) \land (\lnot Q \lor R) \\
& = [\lnot P \land \lnot Q] \lor [\lnot P \land R] \lor [Q \land R] \\
& = [(\lnot P \land \lnot Q \land R) \lor (\lnot P \land \lnot Q \land \lnot R)] \lor [(\lnot P \land Q \land R) \lor (\lnot P \land \lnot Q \land R)] \lor \\
& \phantom{{}={}} [(P \land Q \land R) \lor (\lnot P \land Q \land R)] \\
& = (\lnot P \land \lnot Q \land R) \lor (\lnot P \land \lnot Q \land \lnot R) \lor (\lnot P \land Q \land R) \lor (P \land Q \land R).
\end{align}

Now you should see how the general method works. If you want to redo it without pretending to be as dumb as a computer, some steps can be skipped. In fact, the final form doesn't have to be expanded out in full. You can just try to make both expressions look like this:

$$
(Q \land R) \vee (\lnot P \land \lnot Q).
$$

Comment: This explained it *perfectly* I thought. Makes complete sense now. I think my main problem was simply getting overwhelmed with all of the bookkeeping. How would you like all of your bounties (I was, of course, serious about that)? I'm new to giving bounties in this manner--do I distribute them over separate days or how does that work?

Comment: @crash Don't worry about the bounty. To me, the only thing that matters on this site is that it helps people learn things. And I believe my current reputation is high enough to convince people that I'm not talking non-sense :)

Comment: Are you sure? Your answer really helped me out. I was starting to get beside myself! You know how math can do that to you sometime. Make you go stir-crazy. Well, if you're alright with me not worrying about the bounty, then I won't award the original +1500 bounty, but I will certainly give you a bounty of +250 when the bounty period opens. You deserve it because you really helped me quite a bit, and I'd like to reward you for that, even if it's something as minor as a little reputation bump. :)

Comment: @crash I have to thank you then :)
By the way, if you are interested, you can read about the conjunctive normal form [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Conversion_into_CNF). Disjunctive normal form is essentially the same as the conjunctive normal form when you switch $\land$ and $\lor$. (By that, I mean their definitions are the same. I'm not saying that a disjunctive normal form of one sentence can be converted into a conjunctive normal form by switching $\land$ and $\lor$.)

Comment: Very interesting. Yes, I will read up on it and embrace it. I never took mathematical logic--I just really devoured the little introductory material I encountered a long time ago at the beginning of a basic proofs course. So I have quite a bit to learn. Thanks for the link, comment, and answer! (+250) haha

Answer (score 3):

It is fairly approachable if you split up according to whether $Q$ is true or false.

For conciseness, call the two formulas be $\Phi$ and $\Psi$. We can show that each of them is equivalent to $(R\land Q) \lor (\neg P\land \neg Q)$, and therefore they are equivalent to each other.

More precisely, I will show that $\Xi\land Q \equiv \neg R\land Q$ and $\Xi\land \neg Q\equiv \neg P\land \neg Q$, for $\Xi\in\{\Phi,\Psi\}$. We then have
$$ \begin{align} \Xi \equiv{}& \Xi\land (Q\lor \neg Q) \\
\equiv{}& (\Xi\land Q) \lor (\Xi\land \neg Q) \\
\equiv{}& (R\land Q) \lor (\neg P\land \neg Q) \end{align} $$

Thus there are four computations to do:
$$ \begin{align} \Phi\land Q
\equiv{}& (P\to Q)\land (Q\to R)\land Q \\
\equiv{}& (P\to Q)\land Q \land R \\
\equiv{}& Q\land R \end{align} $$

$$ \begin{align} \Phi\land \neg Q
\equiv{}& (P\to Q)\land (Q\to R)\land \neg Q \\
\equiv{}& (P\to Q)\land (\neg Q\lor R)\land \neg Q \\
\equiv{}& (P\to Q)\land \neg Q \\
\equiv{}& (\neg Q\to \neg P)\land \neg Q\\
\equiv{}& \neg P \land \neg Q \end{align} $$

$$  \begin{align} \Psi\land Q
\equiv{}& (P\to R)\land (P\leftrightarrow Q \lor R\leftrightarrow Q) \land Q \\
\equiv{}& (P\to R)\land ((P\leftrightarrow Q \land Q) \lor (R\leftrightarrow Q)\land Q)) \\
\equiv{}& (P\to R)\land ((P\land Q) \lor (R\land Q)) \\
\equiv{}& (P\to R)\land (P\lor R) \land Q\\
\equiv{}& (\neg P \lor R)\land (P\lor R) \land Q \\
\equiv{}& ((\neg P \land P) \lor R) \land Q \\
\equiv{}& (\bot \lor R) \land Q \\
\equiv{}& R \land Q \end{align} $$

$$ \begin{align} \Psi\land \neg Q
\equiv{}& (P\to R)\land (P\leftrightarrow Q \lor R\leftrightarrow Q) \land \neg Q \\
\equiv{}& (P\to R)\land ((P\leftrightarrow Q \land \neg Q) \lor (R\leftrightarrow Q)\land \neg Q)) \\
\equiv{}& (P\to R)\land ((\neg P\land \neg Q) \lor (\neg R\land \neg Q)) \\
\equiv{}& (P\to R)\land (\neg P\lor \neg R) \land \neg Q\\
\equiv{}& (\neg P \lor R)\land (\neg P\lor \neg R) \land \neg Q \\
\equiv{}& (\neg P \lor (R \land \neg R)) \land \neg Q \\
\equiv{}& (\neg P \lor \bot) \land \neg Q \\
\equiv{}& \neg P \land \neg Q \end{align} $$

Here I've  used distribution plenty of times, as well as rules such as

- $(A\to B)\land A \equiv A\land B$
- $(A\to B)\land B \equiv B$
- $(A\lor B)\land A \equiv A$
- $(A\leftrightarrow B)\land A\equiv A\land B$

Answer (score 3):

If you want a more intuitive proof of the forward direction (the more difficult one) that more displays the gist, probably the best thing is to first show the rule that $\vdash (Q \rightarrow P) \vee (R \rightarrow Q)$. This disjunction holds because

- $Q \rightarrow \bot$ entails $Q \rightarrow P$ ($Q \rightarrow \_$  considered as a function preserves entailment, and $\bot \vdash P$),

  $Q$ entails $R \rightarrow Q$,

  $\vdash (Q \rightarrow \bot) \vee Q$ (the law of excluded middle of classical logic).

Given the rule, it's immediate that

$(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R) \vdash ((P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R)) \wedge ((Q \rightarrow P) \vee (R \rightarrow Q))$.

It follows simply from distributivity that the right hand side (and thus the left hand side) of this entailment entails $(P \leftrightarrow Q) \vee (R \leftrightarrow Q)$. And it is easy to show that

$(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow R) \vdash P \rightarrow R$.

Since a conjunction is entailed if (and only if) both conjuncts are entailed, you're done (with the forward direction).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative chain-of-equivalences proof, which uses some laws of logic that may not be well-known.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\then}{\to}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\gets}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$Below, I will use the fact that $\;\equiv\;$ is associative; and to reduce the number of parentheses, I will just write, e.g., $\;\phi \equiv \psi \equiv \chi\;$.  Also, I will use the fact that $\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\equiv\;$.

We start at the most complex side, and rewrite $\;(P \equiv Q) \;\lor\; (R \equiv Q)\;$ towards the left hand side, under the assumption that $\;P \then R\;$:

$$\calc
  (P \equiv Q) \;\lor\; (R \equiv Q)
\op=\hint{$\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\equiv\;$}
  P \lor (R \equiv Q) \;\equiv\; Q \lor (R \equiv Q)
\op=\hint{$\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\equiv\;$, twice}
  P \lor R \;\equiv\; P \lor Q \;\equiv\; Q \lor R \;\equiv\; Q \lor Q
\op=\hints{assumption $\;P \then R\;$ means $\;P \lor R \equiv R\;$;}\hint{simplify $\;Q \lor Q\;$; reorder equivalences}
  P \lor Q \;\equiv\; Q \;\equiv\; Q \lor R \;\equiv\; R
\op=\hint{write $\;\phi \lor \chi \equiv \chi\;$ as $\;\phi \then \chi\;$, twice}
  (P \then Q) \;\equiv\; (Q \then R)
\op=
\hints{write $\;\phi \equiv \psi\;$ as $\;(\phi \land \psi) \lor (\lnot\phi \land \lnot\psi)\;$}
\hint{-- to introduce our goal $\;(P \then Q) \land (Q \then R)\;$}
  \big((P \then Q) \land (Q \then R)\big) \;\lor\; \big(\lnot (P \then Q) \land \lnot (Q \then R)\big)
\op=\hint{write $\;\phi \then \chi\;$ as $\;\lnot \phi \lor \chi\;$, and DeMorgan, twice}
  \big((P \then Q) \land (Q \then R)\big) \;\lor\; (P \land \lnot Q \land Q \land \lnot R)
\op=\hint{contradiction: $\;\lnot Q \land Q \;\equiv\; \false\;$; simplify}
  (P \then Q) \;\land\; (Q \then R)
\endcalc$$

Now we can wrap up the proof:

$$\calc
  (P \then R) \;\land\; \big((P \equiv Q) \lor (R \equiv Q)\big)
\op=\hint{the above calculation}
  (P \then R) \;\land\; (P \then Q) \;\land\; (Q \then R)
\op=\hint{$\;\then\;$ is transitive}
  (P \then Q) \;\land\; (Q \then R)
\endcalc$$